# where does $PATH get its values from (osx)?

Tags: osx, path

When I type $PATH, among the list of values I see some are from `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d`, but there are also links to python frameworks. Where does it read these from?

Answer (score 2):

When you log on to your computer, the loginwindow.app sets up a basic environment which includes `$HOME`, `$SHELL`, `$TMPDIR`, `$LOGNAME`, `$USER`, and `$PATH`. The environment may also be altered by launch daemons or agent. Or by extending the PATH variable within `launchd`. Typically, the PATH variable is set to the hard coded PATH variable in the kernel.

```
sysctl user.cs_path
user.cs_path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

When you start the terminal emulator, by default, it will call `login` - `login -pf <yourname>` which will setup only those environment variables that have not already set (see `man login`).

Your shell- `$SHELL` then reads the appropriate file in `/etc` that calls `path_helper`. `path_helper` takes the PATH variable that is already set, reads `/etc/paths`, removes duplicates in the current PATH and orders the PATH variable as set in `/etc/paths`, then reads the files within `/etc/paths.d` adds those to the PATH variable, and then adds any paths that were in the original PATH which haven't already been added..

Finally, your $SHELL reads the appropriate rc file for a login shell in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

A program called `path_helper` is run from various `/etc/*` shell rc files by default.

```
$ grep path_helper /etc/* 2>/dev/null
/etc/csh.login:#if ( -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ) then
/etc/csh.login:#    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -c`
/etc/profile:#if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
/etc/profile:#  eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
/etc/zprofile:#if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
/etc/zprofile:# eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
$
```

This is obviously *not* the default; I've disabled `path_helper` and manage `PATH` in my own rc files.